# 1 page served from 2 different servers looks different in 1 browser -- beyond weird

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

This is a prize winner.

I have Apache on my PC and on my remote server.

I have a page that has been a real nuisance to get looking right in both IE (IE7) and FireFox (FF3.0). At the moment it is close enough in the two browsers to live with.

Here's the crazy part. When I look at the page as served by my localhost server and as served by my production remote host server it looks just a little different. The differences all look like matters of margins and/or placement and/or image size.

It doesn't matter whether it is IE or FF. I get 2 close but not identical renderings on IE and the same on FF.

I've done all the basic commonsense trouble shooting I can think of. I've repeated the FTP transfer several times and checked all the file permissions. I've even downloaded the CSS files into the browsers directly just to make sure they still look the same.

By any principles I can think of, what I am seeing SHOULD be impossible. I can't think of anything that would account for this completely bizarre effect.

i'd be very much obliged if you have any thoughts on the subject.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you 110% sure all the browser's page zoom settings are reset to defaults?

Comment: Tatu Ulmanen - how do you accept an answer? I'm looking around the page and don't see anything promising. Maybe it's in the site instructions somewhere. ...

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you actually do not see the version you uploaded to the server but a cached one. (servers cache, your local cache, isp's cache...)
You can try to save the page and the css you get from both, the server and your local machine, and then compare it. I would use a diff tool like tkdiff. Then you know if there are differences in the markup.

When you've downloaded both versions to a local directory you can also check the differences in the browser again. Is it still there?

You can also instruct apache to send the page with the headers "no cache". Then all caching is disabled. The keyword to look for is "cache-control" here. There are many ways to send this information in the headers. (But note: you should not disable caching on a live system as it will slow down the whole thing...)

Comment: Simon. Thanks for the cache-control tip. As it happens, Pekka (above) nailed it on the first guess. But I will make a point of using the cache-control the next time I am trouble shooting such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Tatu Ulmanen & Pekka -- My enthusiastic thanks.

You were right.

a) The content types were, as one would expect identical -- but I hadn't thought of checking it, so thanks for that.

b) Pekka gets the cigar. The browser zoom setting had been altered from window to window in the rush of work, and this made a noticable difference in the layouts -- as one would expect.

Frankly I doubt I would have thought to check that. Ironic no?

May luck smile upon you both.

Comment: Ah! That simple! ;-) FF add-ons like https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/14382/ could help here to avoid situations like that.